# Differentiability implies continuity in higher dimension

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I realize this question has answers all over the place, but I'm still lost. Specifically, I want to prove that given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ that is differentiable at the point $c$, it follows that $f$ is continuous at $c$. The definition of differentiable that I'm using is $f$ is differentiable at $c$ if there exists a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\|f(c+h)-f(c)-L(h)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}}{\|h\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}=0.$$
I understand that the setup is something along these lines:

> By application of the triangle inequality, we have
>   $\|f(c+h)-f(c)\|=\|h\|\cdot\frac{\|f(c+h)-f(c)\|}{\|h\|}\leq\|h\|\cdot\frac{\|f(c+h)-f(c)-L(h)\|}{\|h\|}+\|L(h)\|$

But then all the proofs I've found seem to stop here or shortly after. Sure, it's clear that the RHS inequality goes to $0$ as $h\rightarrow0$. But why is it that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\|f(c+h)-f(c)\|=0$ implies that the function is continuous? I need to show that $\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h)=f(c)$, correct?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^m$, $\|f(c+h) - f(c)\|\to 0$ iff $f(c+h)\to f(c)$.

Comment: @xbh Could you elaborate on how that implies continuity?

Comment: Simply, review the definition of continuity.

Comment: @xbh How does $f(c+h)\rightarrow f(c)$ imply that $\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h)=f(c)$?

Comment: Rewrite $h = c +(h -c)$. No need to be fixated on the choice of alphabets.

Comment: @xbh So something along the lines of $\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(c+(h-c))=f(c)\Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(c)+\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h-c)=f(c)\Rightarrow f(c)+\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h-c)=f(c)\Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h-c)=0\Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow c}(f(h))-\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(c)=0\Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h)-f(c)=0\Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow c}f(h)=f(c)$

Comment: You are confused because the $h$ in the two equations at the end of your questions are not the same. Denote $t=c+h$ and then $\lim\limits_{t\to c}f(t)=f(c)$

Comment: @Serg Thank you!!!

Comment: "But why is it that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\|f(c+h)-f(c)\|=0$ implies that the function is continuous?" OK, I'm not trying to be mean, but this is something you learned in Calc. I.

Comment: @zhw Step 1: Recall facts from many years ago. Step 2: Recognize that you've accidently used the same variable in 2 different contexts. Step 3: Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By application of the triangle inequality, we have
$$||F(c+h)-F(c)||=||h||\cdot\frac{||F(c+h)-F(c)||}{||h||}\leq||h||\cdot\frac{||F(c+h)-F(c)-L(h)||}{||h||}+||L(h)||.$$
Then, because $L$ is a linear map, as $h\rightarrow 0$, the RHS of the inequality goes to $0$. That is,
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}||F(c+h)-F(c)||=0.$$
This is true if and only if 
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}F(c+h)=F(c).$$
Then, denote $t=c+h$. It follows that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow c}F(t)=F(c),$$
and hence $F$ is continuous at $c$.